# Using lighttpd as top layer on play framework to add ssl

Tags: playframework, lighttpd

I want to use SSL over websocket in play framework.
I understand that PLay! 2.1 does not support yet in SSL (or the I missed something)

Reading Play! docs show the option to use lighttpd, which I decided to use.

My question is, how to configure lighttpd.conf that the client connect using WSS to lighttpd and using WS from lighttpd to  Play!?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Update: lighttpd 1.4.46 (released back in 2017) added multiple ways to accept WebSocket connections:

- [lighttpd mod_wstunnel](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModWSTunnel)
- [lighttpd mod_proxy](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModProxy)
- [lighttpd mod_cgi](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModCGI)

To configure lighttpd to use TLS:

- [lighttpd TLS](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_SSL)